# Can you create a kubernetes controller which schedules custom labels?

Tags: kubernetes, controller

Is it possible to create a controller on k8’s which only schedules workloads with an explicit label for certain nodes ?

Thanks in advance
Matt

Comment: nodeAffinity,nodeAntiAffinity,podAffinity & podAntiAffinity gives control on scheduling

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have separate controller to schedule custom labels on nodes. Using taints and tolerations you can control scheduling the pods onto required nodes